# Had and would stick

Tags: verbs

In the following [sentence](https://www.thehindu.com/business/budget/economic-survey-sets-out-blueprint-for-5-trillion-economy/article28283101.ece?homepage=true)

> Further, he said, implicit in the emphasis on private investment was
>   the fact that the government ***had and would stick*** to its fiscal
>   consolidation glide path.

I think **had** and **would** take different forms of verbs after them, so it should be **had stuck and would stick**

Am I right?

Comment: Both versions are fine. If you have a conjunction, the verb follows the word or phrase closest to it. But your version is more unarguably correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct.
But when using a conjunction, the verb used is according to the word **closest** to it. So the example can not be marked wrong either.